# Node app doesn't work after firebase deploy

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, ejs

My Node app works perfectly if you use firebase serve to test on localhost. If I run firebase serve, localhost:5000/blogs will render my website.

However, after Firebase deploy, if I go to https://garylai-b77af.firebaseapp.com/blogs , it says "Error: could not handle the request".

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's my index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
mongoose = require("mongoose"),
express = require("express"),
app = express();

//App Config
mongoose.connect('//the correct url, username and password to mlab omitted here');
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));//for serving custom stylesheet
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    snippet: String,
   created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

//INDEX ROUTE
app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
    if(err){console.log("Error!");}
 else {
    res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});//pass blogs the data under the name blogs to index
 }
})});

//Restful Routes
 app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.redirect("/blogs");
});

//SHOW ROUTE
app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    } else{
        res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
    }
})
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```